# Configuring a new View Screen in JIRA

Tags: jira

I am attempting to reconfigure the "View Issue" screen on a basically default JIRA 4.4 installation. So far, I am unable to actually see this new screen I have created in action on any issues, and I am unsure what I am doing wrong -- though it is probably something simple.

The steps I took were:

- Created a new screen
- Created a new screen scheme
- Attached my new screen to the "View Issue" action of the new scheme
- Attached my screen scheme to a new issue type scheme
- Attached my issue type scheme to my project
- Performed a re-index (not sure this is necessary)

However, I still do not see my new view screen in place of the old one; all of the normal defaults are still there. I also tried restarting JIRA to see if that changed anything, but it did not.

Is there anything I am missing? I assume it is just something minor, but maybe JIRA can't do what I am trying to do? Everything I read seems to indicate you can fully configure the issue view via the administrative tool rather than hacking around in the code, but maybe I am just misinterpreting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by sentence

> Attached my screen scheme to a new issue type scheme

that you have created a new *Issue Type Screen Scheme*, make sure that target project is configured to use the newly created Issue Type Screen Scheme.

Also note that some fields cannot be actually removed from the issue view like *Resolution* and *Issue Type* fields. However they have effect on screen for edit operations. If these fields are present on the edit screen, they can be edited inline on view screen. Otherwise they will be just visible and not editable.